# How to update a variable in a discord.py buttons class?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I'm trying to make a command that has buttons that sends a different question with different options each time it's executed, the questions/options are pulled from a text file. I'm using a counter to tell the code to pull a different question, but it seems to be pulling the same one always.

This is the code I'm using for the buttons:

```
class buttons(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    with open("temp.txt", "r") as fp:
        for i, line in enumerate(fp):
            global count
            count = 0
            if i == count:
                answer = json.loads(line)
                global current_question
                current_question = {}
                current_question["Question"] = answer.get("Question")
                current_question["Option1"] = answer.get("Option1")
    global option1
    option1 = current_question.get("Option1")
    @discord.ui.button(label=option1, style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple)
    async def op1(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
    ...
```

And this is the code for the command that when executed, should raise the counter by one:

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send(current_question.get("Question"), view=buttons())
    global count
    count +=1
```

I have to keep the buttons in a class, and I just don't know how to get the count variable to update there, It's stuck on 0 and it's sending the same questions and options.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@discord.ui.button` decorator allows you to create a button, relate it to a `callback` and add it to a view in a practical way, but when you have variable parameters for these buttons, I suggest that you create and add the buttons manually. For example:

```py
class OptionButton(discord.ui.Button):
    def __init__(self, option: str):
        super().__init__(label=option, style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple)

    async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        if self.label == self.view.answer:
            await interaction.response.send_message("Right answer!")
        else:
            await interaction.response.send_message("Wrong answer!")


class QuestionView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, options: list[str], answer: str):
        self.answer = answer
        for op in options:
            self.add_item(OptionButton(op))
        super().__init__()


count = 0


@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    global count
    
    with open("temp.txt", "r") as fp:
        lines = fp.read().splitlines()
    question = json.loads(lines[count])
    await ctx.send(
        content=question["question"],
        view=QuestionView(question["options"], question["answer"])
    )
    count += 1
```

> Note that I'm accessing the `question`, `options` and `answer` keys. Your dictionary doesn't have these keys, but I think this would be the best way to store question data.